# Does ConvertTo-XLSX require excel to be installed on the Sitecore server for use in Sitecore PSE?

Tags: excel, powershell, sitecore

I am trying to generate an excel report with multiple worksheets from Sitecore PSE. I have seen several methods that require the excel com object and didn't know if this is required in Sitecore PSE or not.

Comment: Even if it's actually off topic: Take a look at the module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) from Doug Finke.

Comment: Trying to use ImportExcel with Sitecore PSE has been extremely problematic so far. If anyone knows of a good way to may it work with Sitecore PSE, I would be more than happy to continue down that path.